# django can i store the type of a model in a variable for use in a method call?

Tags: django

i'm not sure what terms python uses for objects - forgive my lack of python know how!

Effectively, how can i do this:

```
strToObject = {'story':Story,'post':Post}

def post(self,request):
    type = request.POST['theTypeInTheForm']
    id = request.POST['idInTheForm']
    get_object_or_404(strToObject.get(type,None),id)
```

so what this is doing is taking a value from a form field, working out what type we're talking about, and then pulling from the db the right type from the id.

I don't quite know how to do this though. (the form is really for a rating button, so i don't really have a whole form behind it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use [ContentTypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), which is a model containing all the different models defined in your app.

Comment: ah. that's a pretty convenient system django has set up.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to be more careful getting the model from `strToObject`. As it stands, if `type` is not one of "story" or "post", `get_object_or_404` will be fed `None` as the model, and your code will blow up. Do something like this instead:

```
model = strToObject.get(type) # `None` is the "default" default
if model is not None:
    get_object_or_404(model, id=id)
```

Second, as I indicated in the above code, you can't just pass the `id` as is to `get_object_or_404`, you need to specify what field on the model the value should be looked up on, hence `id=id`.

Third, you should be using `get` on `request.POST` to get the `type` and the `id`. As it is now, if they're not in the form for whatever reason, your code will blow up with an `IndexError`:

```
type = request.POST.get('theTypeInTheForm')
id = request.POST.get('idInTheForm')
```

Then, you should check that the values are not `None` before proceeding:

```
if type is not None and id is not None:
    # the rest of your code
```

Comment: hey! thanks for the code review - and i mean that. they're good points you raise. i have to go with daniel's answer - because it answers the  question i asked, but i do appreciate the input you gave a great deal!